# Issue with Running total in Access

Tags: ms-access, cumulative-sum

I am trying to add a running total to an access query and after watching a video on how to do it I came up with the following;

```
SELECT Analyst, [Grant ID], [Fiscal Year], Available, Recovered, Bal,

(SELECT SUM(Bal) FROM QueryTest WHERE C.[Fiscal Year] >= [Fiscal Year] and C.[Grant ID] = [Grant ID]) as
RunningBalance

From QueryTest AS C

ORDER BY Analyst, [Grant ID];
```

but when I run it it indicates that

the database engine does not recognize C.[fiscal Year] as a valid field suggesting something is wrong with the use of the alias but I cant figure out what it is.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Edit question to show sample data as text table.

Answer (score 1):

Try the C alias in the inner query not the outer.

```
SELECT Analyst, [Grant ID], [Fiscal Year], Available, Recovered, Bal,

(SELECT SUM(C.Bal) FROM QueryTest AS C 
 WHERE C.[Fiscal Year] >= QueryTest.[Fiscal Year] 
 AND C.[Grant ID] = QueryTest.[Grant ID]) as RunningBalance

FROM QueryTest

ORDER BY Analyst, [Grant ID];
```

A simpler alternative is to build a report and use textbox RunningSum property.

Comment: Thanks for the information provided. I will utilize it and see what happens.